# Is it possible to recover data from a partial tar.gz file?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, tar, gzip

I was uploading my backup tar.gz file over several sessions. With one session still to go, I thought I would take a break. That was the last time I was able to use that pc - dead HD. The original tar.gz file was lost beyond recovery. I still have the 80% which I had already uploaded. Is it possible to extract anything from this partial tar.gz file? If so, how?
Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to extract?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/201392/4464570

Comment: I haven't tried to extract yet, because I KNOW the file is incomplete. When I were a lad, compression files had all of the "index" details at the tail end of the file, exactly what this file does not have.